# How to improve Cloud composer health?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

I recently built 120 dags using cloud composer.  They all functioned *for a while*.

They were all approximately the same.  Each used python operator.  Each made API calls to google search console.  Each collected 7-9k rows of GSC data into a pandas dataframe, then uploaded this to GCS buckets and BigQuery (partitioned and clustered).

Occasionally I'd have all fail one day because the GSC auth token had been revoked, but no problem, create new credentials, upload and continue.  That situation lasted a couple of months.  Now nothing runs.

From the start, the cloud composer health had occasional red spots, but now the health is static red every day.

I have found documentation about how to check the health, but not how to find why the health is so poor and fix it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you confirm if your Airflow Dags are running? When you say health is red static, are you referring to Composer’s `Environment Health` metric showing unhealthy?

Comment: Sadly, they have all stopped. Yes, that's the graph I mean - sorry I should have been more specific. Environment overview - Environment health (Airflow monitoring DAG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment health metric depends on a Composer-managed DAG named `airflow_monitoring` which is triggered periodically by the airflow-monitoring pod. If this DAG isn't deleted, you can check the airflow-monitoring logs to see if there are any problems related to reading the DAG's run statuses. Consequently,  you can also try troubleshooting the error in Cloud Logging using the  filter:

```
resource.type="cloud_composer_environment"
severity=ERROR
```

The liveness check failure could be due to the following reasons:

- Any resource constraint(Memory and CPU)
- Known issue with the    composer version. Please check composer
  [release

  notes](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes) for any
  known issues.
- Airflow configuration as `core:default_timezone`(If    you’ve
  configured `core: default_timezone` airflow configuration    composer
  environment health will be shown as unhealthy. It is a     known
  issue and the composer product team is working on the    resolution.)

Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/monitoring-environments#environment_health) for information on Cloud Composer’s environment health metric.

Comment: Thanks Sakshi - it appears to be a resource constraint

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky enough to talk to someone from Google yesterday who said what I need to do is recreate my cloud composer environment because I have insufficient CPU.  He suggested the flexible choice when recreating.